# The path to the mounted drive in macos

Tags: macos, mount, macos-catalina

I have mounted a network drive into my mac but I don't know where it is mounted. In Linux when you mount an external drive it always mounts in \dev but in mac it is not clear to me in what path it is mounted. Any reflection would be appreciated.

Comment: The default path is `/Volumes`

Comment: Which network protocol are you using to mount the drive? The `mount` command should list all mounted drives including SMB and NFS mounts.

Comment: @Rudedog do you mean just using mount command? without any option or argument?

Comment: Yes, `mount` without arguments lists all mounted drives.

Comment: Yet another un-answered question re mounting network drives on macOS. I wonder when we'll learn how bad Apple's documentation issues are. How do you get to be the world's largest corporation by *cheating* customers out of documentation?